# long process in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

My situation is this:

was created a page that will run a long process . ... This process consists in:
- Read a file. Csv, for each row of the file wil be created an invoice...in the end of this process shows a successful message.

for this it was decided to use an updatepanel so that the process is asynchronous and can display an UpdateProgress while waiting to finish the process ... for this in the property of scriptmanagment was added the AsyncPostBackTimeout = 7200 (2 hours) and also timeout was increased in the web.config of the app as in qa and production servers.

Tests were made in the localhost as a qa server and works very well, the problem arises when testing the functionality on the production server.

that makes:
file is loaded and starts the process ... during this period is running the UpdateProgress but is only taking between 1 or 2 min and ends the execution without displaying the last message, as if truncated the process. When reviewing the invoices created are creating only the top 10 records of the file.(from a file with 50,100 or + rows)

so I would like to help me with this, because i don't know what could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

asp.net is not suited for long running processes.

The default page timeout for IIS is 110 seconds (90 for .net 1.0). You can increase this, but it is not recommended.

If you must do it, here is the setting:

```
<system.web>
   ...
   <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180"/>
   ...
<\system.web>
```

Refer [httpRuntime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx)

Pass on this work to a windows service, WCF or a stand alone exe.
Use your page to get the status of the process from that application.

Here is an example that shows how to use [workflows for long running processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd296718.aspx).

You move the bulk of the processing out of asp.net, and free its threads to handle page requests.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ... I'll check